# How to rewrite nginx to execute a php file before serving static content?

Tags: apache, nginx, url-rewriting

I am trying to do this in `nginx` but I just cannot get it to work:

```
# protect images
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(bmp|gif|ico|jpe|jpeg|jpg|png)$
RewriteRule .* /path-to-file.php [L,QSA]
```

Tried it with `try_files` and `rewrite`, any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To rewrite all image URIs to a specific PHP script, you could use a regex location and an internal rewrite:

```
location ~* \.(bmp|gif|ico|jpe|jpeg|jpg|png)$ {
  rewrite ^ /path/to/file.php;
}
```